# Passing property as pros in react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am in the process of learning react. Here i got stuck in some basic problems. I learn concept of props and parent-child components in react, but when i try to implement it, it shows error. Please help. I have one parent component named 'Portfolio' and one child component named 'PortfolioBox'. I try to pass title props in PortfolioBox. Here is my sample code. Issue comes while starting the react app 'npm start'. It shows error 'Portfolio is not defined'.

Portfolio Component

```
import React from 'react';
import PortfolioBox from './PortfolioBox';

import './portfolio.css';

function Portfolio()
{
    return (
        <div className="row portfolio-container">
            <PortfolioBox title="One" />
            <PortfolioBox title="Two" />
            <PortfolioBox title="Three" />
            <PortfolioBox title="four" />


        </div>
    )
}

export default Portfolio;
```

Portfolio Box Component

```
import React from 'react';

function PortfolioBox(props)
{
    console.log(props);
    return(
        <div className="col-md-4 portfolio-box">
            <h3>{props.title}</h3>
            <p>Description</p>

        </div>
    )
}


export default PortfolioBox;
```

App.js File

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <Portfolio />

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: whats the error you are getting? Show us the error

Comment: I got 'Portfolio not defined error'

Comment: Consider adding your App.js file

Comment: App.js file added

Comment: You don't import Portfolio in App...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an import statement in your `app.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import Portfolio from './Portfolio'; // If your file is in the same directory

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <Portfolio />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to figure out this simple error.